# Getting Instagram Photos With Specific Hashtag

Tags: php, curl, instagram, instagram-api

On the main page of one of my sites I display an Instagram feed of the 3 most recent pictures. I've achieved this with the following code:

```
function rudr_instagram_api_curl_connect( $api_url ){
    $connection_c = curl_init(); // initializing
    curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url ); // API URL to connect
    curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 ); // return the result, do not print
    curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20 );
    $json_return = curl_exec( $connection_c ); // connect and get json data
    curl_close( $connection_c ); // close connection
    return json_decode( $json_return ); // decode and return
}
$access_token = 'access_token';
$image_return = 3;
$user_search = rudr_instagram_api_curl_connect("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=".$access_token);

$user_id = $user_search->data[0]->id; // or use string 'self' to get your own media
$return = rudr_instagram_api_curl_connect("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=".$access_token."&count=".$image_return);

// var_dump( $return ); // if you want to display everything the function returns

foreach ($return->data as $post) {
    echo '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 mb-3 text-center">
           <a href="'.$post->link.'" target="_blank">
           <img src="' . $post->images->standard_resolution->url . '"  class="img-fluid img-thumbnail bx-shadow"/>
           </a>
           <p><i class="fa fa-tag" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' . $post->caption->text . '<br><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> '.$post->likes->count.' <i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i> '.$post->comments->count.'<br><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' . date('M j, Y', $post->created_time) . '</p>
          </div>';
}
```

Lately I've been uploading photos to Instagram that I don't want to necessarily display on the site so I figured I'd find a way to only retrieve images with a specific hashtag. Upon a quick Google search multiple solutions popped up but one stuck out that was similar to my existing code. This solution can be found here: [Fetch All Photos With A Hashtag](http://www.99points.info/2015/04/instagram-api-fetch-all-photos-with-a-specific-hashtag-using-php/)

I noticed in the solution that there was simply a `tags` variable in the URL so I modified my code by adding a variable of `$hashtag = "bodypiercing";` and adding it to the URL as `$return = rudr_instagram_api_curl_connect("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/".$hashtag."/users/self/media/recent?access_token=".$access_token."&count=".$image_return);`.

Here is that full code:

```
function rudr_instagram_api_curl_connect( $api_url ){
    $connection_c = curl_init(); // initializing
    curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url ); // API URL to connect
    curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 ); // return the result, do not print
    curl_setopt( $connection_c, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20 );
    $json_return = curl_exec( $connection_c ); // connect and get json data
    curl_close( $connection_c ); // close connection
    return json_decode( $json_return ); // decode and return
}
$access_token = 'access_token';
$image_return = 3;
$hashtag = "bodypiercing";
$user_search = rudr_instagram_api_curl_connect("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent?access_token=".$access_token);

$user_id = $user_search->data[0]->id; // or use string 'self' to get your own media
$return = rudr_instagram_api_curl_connect("https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/".$hashtag."/users/self/media/recent?access_token=".$access_token."&count=".$image_return);

// var_dump( $return ); // if you want to display everything the function returns

foreach ($return->data as $post) {
    echo '<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 mb-3 text-center">
           <a href="'.$post->link.'" target="_blank">
           <img src="' . $post->images->standard_resolution->url . '"  class="img-fluid img-thumbnail bx-shadow"/>
           </a>
           <p><i class="fa fa-tag" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' . $post->caption->text . '<br><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> '.$post->likes->count.' <i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i> '.$post->comments->count.'<br><i class="fa fa-clock-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> ' . date('M j, Y', $post->created_time) . '</p>
          </div>';
}
```

However this results in the following:

`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home/jesse666toxik/public_html/php/index.main.php on line 42`

`Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
/home/jesse666toxik/public_html/php/index.main.php on line 42`

What might I have done wrong for this one variable to do this?

Results of `var_dump`:

```
Notice
: Undefined property: stdClass::$data in
/home/jesse666toxik/public_html/php/index.main.php
on line
37


Notice
: Trying to get property of non-object in
/home/jesse666toxik/public_html/php/index.main.php
on line
37

NULL 
Notice
: Trying to get property of non-object in
/home/jesse666toxik/public_html/php/index.main.php
on line
42


Warning
: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
/home/jesse666toxik/public_html/php/index.main.php
on line
42
```

Comment: Uncomment the `var_dump($return)`. What's being returned? Your code expects it to be an object, with a `data` parameter that contains an array. Is that the case?

Comment: Your `$return` variable appears to be returning a user, the api call is the same as that used for `$user_search`

Comment: @ceejayoz Edited and included results of `var_dump`.

@MacroMan that was originally an example from a tutorial. I'm not sure why it was like that but it worked.

Comment: Whoops realized I posted results of `var_dump` with the working code. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the information on the page you have linked to you are using the wrong url, you have inserted part of the hashtag url into your original users url.

Quoted article uses this url:

```
$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/'.$tag.'/media/recent?client_id='.$client_id;
```

As always, the answer can be found in the [API documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/).  You can't search by hashtags from a specific user.

Comment: Well I'm using `users/self` in my URL since I'm retrieving my own images. It just seems that inserting `/tags/hashtag` to my URL should still limit the return. I'll do some work and try that URL though.

Comment: Sadly that URL is asking for an access_token which I have. When added it doesn't return the images. I've put the URL directly into the browser not the code and this is what I got `{"meta": {"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthPermissionsException", "error_message": "This request requires scope=public_content, but this access token is not authorized with this scope. The user must re-authorize your application with scope=public_content to be granted this permissions."}}`

Comment: There are only 3 endpoints for tag requests from the API. Get information about a tag object. Get a list of recently tagged media and Search for tags by name. No option to limit by user. Your best bet would be to use a hashtag nobody else will use for the images you want on your website and then search for that

Comment: Your access_token doesn't have the permissions required for that API call. You need to request a new one and approve the permissions for the new scopes

Comment: I've read some on this permission that is needed and it says applications are no longer accepted. Now I'm really at a loss.